# What's the biggest subset of $R$ for which $\sin(x)$ is injective?

Tags: trigonometry

My guess is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, although there are many others of this size for which $\sin x$ would be injective, but I'm not sure...

Comment: That may depend on what you understand by "biggest subset". For instance, $\sin$ is injective on $\Bbb Z$, which is unbounded, and in a certain sense could be considered "bigger" than $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in that this is the biggest subset, and that there are many (in fact infinitely many) subsets of the same size. You could generalise the answer for $n$ where $n$ is an integer.

e.g.

$R=\Big[\frac{(n-1)\pi}{2},\frac{n\pi}{2}\Big], \forall n  \in \mathbb{N}$